# Directory path: From static string to dynamic OO path

Tags: c#

I'm killing some time by decorating the XmlSerializer and I came across a bump on the road.

When I'm specifying a file path to deserialize, I'm currently assigning a string that could look like the following:

```
XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
Car newCar = handler.GetSingle<Car>("Vehicles\\Cars\\Car1.xml");
```

I figured it would be a neat if I could assign this path through objects (potentially dynamically created and filled at runtime):

```
public class FolderFileModel 
{
    public string FolderFileName { get; set;}
    public string FullPath { get; set;}
    public string FileType { get; set;}
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FullPath;
    }
}

public static class Vehicles : FolderFileModel
{
    public static Cars Cars { get; set; }
    public static Trucks Trucks { get; set; }
    public static Motorcycle Motorcycle { get; set; }
}

public static class Cars : FolderFileModel 
{
    public static Car Car1 { get; set;}
    public static Car Car2 { get; set;}
}

public static class Car : FolderFileModel 
{
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
Car newCar = handler.GetSingle<Car>(Vehicles.Cars.Car1);
```

Assigning the objects runtime with the correct values is not a problem, the problem is that I obviously need the assigned data at compile time. (Hardcoding isn't an option, but I'm open to other ideas as to how this could be implemented)

**What I've considered so far:**

1. ExpandoObject - Wouldn't work in this scenario, as I'd have to store the path data to be able to use it compile time.
2. Reflection.Emit - I'm concerned that this approach wouldnt be very optimized and ultimately make the decorator class too slow.
3. XML to .cs using T4 templates. - Lastly I considered dynamically mapping the directory hierarchy in an XML file and generate the classes from that.

I've never worked with T4 templates before so I figured I'd ask if there's a simpler solution to this problem (other than hardcoding the directory hierarchy)
As it seems like quite a bit of work and might not be worth trouble in my project.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: Knowing the directory and file paths at compile time and therefor (I guess) prevent exceptions caused by wrong or none existant paths. I doubt the benefits will outweight the cons though, but I think it's an interesting topic and could be a neat little feature.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you go from `Car1` to `"Vehicles\\Cars\\Car1.xml"` or what exactly you're asking. Can't you just use a string constant, like `FileLocations.Car1 = "Vehicles\\Cars\\Car1.xml"`, and then call like `GetSingle<Car>(FileLocations.Car1)`?

Comment: Car1.FullPath would contain "Vehicles\\Cars\\Car1.xml", and yes I could do that, but I'd have to hard code every single path then. The idea is to dynamically generate a directory map based on all the subfolders and files, store it in e.g. classes, so it can be called with the GetSingle(Vehicles.Cars.Car1)

Comment: Please use @username to notify people of your response. :) Anyway it's still unclear what the variables are here. From the code you show, you expect two files (Car1.xml and Car2.xml) to be present somewhere. Only those two? Not Car4.xml through Car99.xml? Can they be in a different directory? Or do you want to find all XML files in the "Vehicles\Cars" directory? In the latter case you obviously can't enforce that at compile-time, but have to iterate at runtime. For that you could use a dictionary, like `{ "Car5", "Vehicles\Cars\Car5.xml" }`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I don't think you understand the problem. If I wanted to hardcode my path's, the problem would be solved at that. What I want to accomplish and I know can be done with option #2 and #3, is to generate and store classes at runtime based on the directory hierarchy. After that I'd then be able to call those path's through the classes at compile time. Vehicles would show it's properties (Cars, Trucks etc.) as they wouldve been generated at the past runtime, because those folders were existant in the Vehicles folder. I'm only asking if there's a simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: Alright, so either by you or through some external intervention, files can end up in your resource directory, and you would like to be able to access these files in code through a statically-typed way, for example by generating a class that contains the paths to those files (like `Vehicles.Cars.Car2`), which yields either the path to the file or the deserialized object from that file. Yes, T4 templates sound like exactly the way to do that. Or you could add the XML files to a Resource file, which also exposes its resources as properties. Is the latter also an option?

Comment: @CodeCaster, What kind of benefits would I gain by addings the xml files to a resource file?

Comment: A resource file exposes the resources you put in it as properties, see [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx): _"To access a resource at run-time, simply reference it as you would any other class member [...] `System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap1 = myProject.Properties.Resources.Image01;`"_. Of course it's not as automatic as you would like it, but it's very easy to set up and use. And of course that'll still expose the XML file (as Stream), not the deserialized form of the object it holds.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Interesting stuff. I'll probably still use T4 over that, but thanks anyway.